# C# Crystal Report Date field in the format of D D M M Y Y Y Y with character spaces

Tags: c#, date, crystal-reports, format, field

I'm creating an application to print details to a existing form with blocks. I need to print the characters to those blocks.
Since, the default format gives me the date as dd/mm/yyyy I need to figure out a way to print the date in the format of D D M M Y Y Y Y.

Also I found a link where they explain a method to achieve this. But I don't understand what they are trying there.
You can have a look at the [link](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=16205).

Your support is highly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the link you provided there is a formula field. To achieve what you need create a new formula field.

Now lets look at the formula.

```
    totext({AP_CheckWrk.CheckDate}, "yyyyMMdd")


mid({@Date to text},1,1)&" "&mid({@Date to text},2,1)&" "&mid({@Date to text},3,1)&" "&mid({@Date to text},4,1)&" "&mid({@Date to text},5,1)&" "&mid({@Date to text},6,1)&" "&mid({@Date to text},7,1)&" "&mid({@Date to text},8,1)
```

The first part of the forumla below, converts your datetime into a string using the ToText operator.

```
totext({AP_CheckWrk.CheckDate}, "yyyyMMdd")
```

The next part locates the ordinal position of each charictor, and inserts a space between each, so for example:

```
({@Date to text},2,1)&" "
```

Will give you the second character  of the date, (for examples sake lets say it's 9) followed by a space.

This is done systematically for every part of your new date string to give you a format of

```
X X X X X X X X
```

EDIT!!!!

Create a formula called Date

Paste: `totext({YourDateFieldHere}, "yyyyMMdd")`

Then create a new formula and paste the following

> mid({@Date},1,1)&" "&mid({@Date},2,1)&" "&mid({@Date},3,1)&"
>   "&mid({@Date},4,1)&" "&mid({@Date},5,1)&" "&mid({@Date},6,1)&"
>   "&mid({@Date},7,1)&" "&mid({@Date},8,1)

I might not have explained properly but as you can see, the second formula calls the @Date formula created when we did the formula named "Date"

Then you need to drag the second formula onto the report :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But when I try to run the formula it says "The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.". Can you please tell me what might be the problem?

Comment: Can you confirm you are using Crystal syntax, as apposed to basic syntax?

Copy and paste in a comment exactly what you are attempting. Thanks :)

Comment: Please follow the steps in my edit. It should work for you then.